# Is it possible to save data in an order in mysql or mongodb against a particular field?

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I have a usecase wherein I need to maintain ordered data against a particular field either in mongodb or mysql. Is is possible to do that? I can always retrieve data in order by using an orderby clause but I need to save the rows in ordered format in database, something like inserting into a sorted tree. Performance of database is not a concern.

Comment: i understand nothing !'

Comment: It's not really that clear what you are asking here and it's generally a bit too broad to ask of multiple storage engines in one question. Honestly they are chalk and cheese to their intended best use cases. You would probably be better served by describing your use case more completely as well as pitching to each community separately.

Comment: Why do you need to save it ordered?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a usecase wherein I need to maintain ordered data against a particular field either in mongodb or mysql. Is is possible to do that? I can always retrieve data in order by using an orderby clause but I need to save the rows in ordered format in database, something like inserting into a sorted tree.

Up to this point, I had imagined you wanted the data to be stored in the desired order for performance reasons—but then you go on to say...

> Performance of database is not a concern.

Which leaves me completely stumped as to what you're trying to accomplish or why.

SQL **tables** are not "ordered".  SQL **indexes** (which are often implemented as "sorted trees") are.  One can build multiple different indexes over the same table.  The RDBMS will then use such indexes to improve the performance of queries upon the table, however the underlying data storage is unaffected.

So, the answer to your question as literally posed is "no"—however, all of the benefits (i.e. performance, which apparently is not a concern to you) can be derived through the use of indexes.

Comment: thanks for replying i was not clear I meant insertion performance is not  a concern as it will happen async, the read performance is very much  a concern, in fact that is the whole idea to remove an extra step of sorting and increase performance in read. Do you hav any idea of nosql scenario can this be achieved there.